# Carthage build umbrella framework

Tags: ios, carthage

We are developing a dynamic umbrella framework which consist of several other frameworks. Our framework structure is in below

- Base.framework

  - SubFramework1
  - SubFramework2

    - SubFramework2.1
    - SubFramework2.2
  - SubFramework3

And our xcode project file for the umbrella framework(Base.framework) is structured like this.
But when I execute **carthage build** command , it finds some of the sub frameworks and doesnt able to find some of the sub frameworks. 
What should I do in order to compile the framework as its structured in our xcode project

You can see our framework in the below link:
https://github.com/Kandy-IO/test-cp

(All the subframeworks are in SubFrameworks folder of CpaaSSDK.framework)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the sub frameworks are exposed to carthage build system by selecting them as shared schemes.

[Shared schemes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ksP.png)

As mentioned in carthage doc on github.

> Share your Xcode schemes
>
> Carthage will only build Xcode schemes that are shared from your
>   .xcodeproj. You can see if all of your intended schemes build
>   successfully by running carthage build --no-skip-current, then
>   checking the Carthage/Build folder.
>
> If an important scheme is not built when you run that command, open
>   Xcode and make sure that the scheme is marked as Shared, so Carthage
>   can discover it.

Doc Link - https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#share-your-xcode-schemes